# Grouping string variables into factors in R

Tags: r

The application here is grouping U.S. states into regions.

```
group1 <- c("ME", "NH", "VT", "MA", "CT", "RI")
group2 <- c("FL", "GA", "AL", "MS", "LA")
```

My data looks like:

```
SomeVar | State
---------------
300     | AL
331     | GA
103     | MA
500     | FL
```

And I would like to add a "region" column to the data according to the groupings above, like so:

```
SomeVar | State | Region
------------------------
300     | AL    | 2
331     | GA    | 2
103     | MA    | 1
500     | FL    | 2
```

Is there a straightforward way to assign factors based on groupings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
group1 <- c("ME", "NH", "VT", "MA", "CT", "RI")
group2 <- c("FL", "GA", "AL", "MS", "LA")

grouptab <- rbind(data.frame(State=group1,grp=1),
                  data.frame(State=group2,grp=2))
DF <- read.table(text="SomeVar  State
300      AL
331      GA
103      MA
500      FL",header=TRUE)

merge(DF,grouptab)
```

Or more generally:

```
groupList <- list(group1,group2)
grouptab <- data.frame(State=unlist(groupList),
                       grp=rep(seq_along(groupList),
                               sapply(groupList,length)))
```

(there may be other ways to do this -- I tried `mapply` but couldn't figure it out quickly)

I think suitable arguments to `merge` (e.g. `all`, `all.x`, `all.y`) would handle the missing-group cases in various ways.

Answer (score 1):

```
group1 <- c("ME", "NH", "VT", "MA", "CT", "RI")
group2 <- c("FL", "GA", "AL", "MS", "LA")

DF <- read.table(text="SomeVar  State
300      AL
331      GA
103      MA
500      FL",header=TRUE)

DF$Region <- NA
DF$Region[DF$State %in% group1] <- 1
DF$Region[DF$State %in% group2] <- 2

#   SomeVar State Region
# 1     300    AL     2
# 2     331    GA     2
# 3     103    MA     1
# 4     500    FL     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data frame is called `df` and that all the states are either in group 1 or in group 2 you can do

```
df$region <- ifelse(df$state %in% group1, 1, 2)
```

Comment: What if a state is in neither group?